# Which fonts are pre-installed in Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: 13.04, fonts, debian, language-support

My laptop runs Ubuntu 13.04, and is able to display text in foreign languages (e.g. Chinese) on websites.

But this is not the case with Debian. Despite installing all locales, my browser doesn't display text in foreign languages.

So, does anyone know/have a list of all the font packages that Ubuntu Desktop comes pre-installed with? (So, that I can simply install them on Debian.)

**NOTE:** I need a list of **packages**, as I need to do this via command-line.

Comment: @Alvar Please read this: http://askubuntu.com/q/313239/36459

Comment: @Alvar I am using Debian (and Ubuntu).

Comment: @Alvar Are you sure Debian is off-topic? I've been told otherwise. Besides, the 'Debian' tag suggest the same, as I see it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/tags/debian/info Questions about using Debian are off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing/running:

`sudo apt-get install xvfb xfonts-base xfonts-75dpi xfonts-100dpi`

`sudo apt-get install xfonts-intl-chinese`

and finally

`sudo apt-get install xfonts-wqy`

Hope it helps

Comment: Excellent. As I see it, `xfonts-intl-*` packages install fonts for most modern languages.

Comment: Has this worked?

Comment: Yes, I can see the text now.