# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server fonts & rendering problem

Tags: 16.04, server, fonts, desktop-environments

I'm having an issue where i'm using node-canvas to render images for an application we previously hosted on a server running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop.

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop, they work fine and fonts render properly in multiple languages. We recently switched to the headless Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server and all the fonts are pretty messed up and not rendering properly. Support for languages other than English is also gone (Foreign language letters are rendered as weird icons instead)

Does anyone have a list of packages or instructions for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop that I can install on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server so I can get the same fonts & font rendering capability?

I tried to find the list of packages but there are so many that I do not know what packages have to be installed.

I've also tried this: [Which fonts are pre-installed in Ubuntu Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313298/which-fonts-are-pre-installed-in-ubuntu-desktop) but it doesnt seem to be working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command

```
apt show ubuntu-desktop
```

and pick the fonts packages under "Depends:" and "Recommends:".